# Preg_replace &, ; and #

Tags: php, codeigniter, preg-replace

I am using following PHP code to escape user input however &,# and ; can not be escaped since these are also used in the codes of other special characters. Here is my code

```
>$data = preg_replace("/</", "&lt;", $data);
>$data = preg_replace("/>/", "&gt;", $data);
>$data = preg_replace("/\"/", "&quot;", $data);
>$data = preg_replace("/\(/", "&#40;", $data);
>$data = preg_replace("/\)/", "&#41;", $data);
>$data = preg_replace("/'/", "&#39;", $data);
>$data = preg_replace("/{/", "&#123;", $data);
>$data = preg_replace("/}/", "&#125;", $data);
>$data = preg_replace("/\`/", "&#96;", $data);//tick mark
>$data = preg_replace("/\[/", "&#91;", $data);
>$data = preg_replace("/\]/", "&#93;", $data);
>$data = preg_replace("/\=/", "&#61;", $data);
```

SO can you tell me how to escape &, # and ; with out disturbing rest of the code. Am sure this must have been asked many times to if u can direct me to relevant post.  Also if some firend has created his own code / module / class for escaping that will be really cool

Comment: You don't really use any regular expressions here so `str_replace()` would be much faster (assuming you only need these entities converted and don't want to use `htmlentities()`).

Comment: Why don't you just use [`htmlentities`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php)?

Comment: Ok sir can u plz tell me how html entitles will get this done??

Answer (score 3):

You better should use `htmlentites()`, which will do all work for you :

```
$data = htmlentities($data, ENT_QUOTES);
```

[Documentations here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php)

Comment: yes my friend i know that but some people have disease of looking under the hood... so can u plz tell me how  htmlentities get this done. the problem is after we have converted { into say &#123; now how can we convert # or & or ;... since that will screw up &#123;

Comment: @BilalTariq: no it won't. The function takes care of that.

Comment: First thing : if you replace chars in the right order, you shouldn't have problems : replace & ; and # first, then you're sure to not replace bad ones.